# Do mysql querys in python with zip file

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Im trying to do some querys on my data base, but the file is to large and is spending to much time, exists some way to upload one zip file with those querys to my table?

ps: the file have between 350Mb to 500Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the zip file somewhere else on your server and simply store the name or the file location string in your dB.

Mysql really isn't intended to store large files or better yet zip folders.

Then when you go to retrieve it just unload the file location into an `<a>` tag it will link to it.